# Creating a value list from dictionary with partial indices:values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to convert a dictionary of index:value into a list with those values. for indices that does not appear in the dictionary, 0 can be used.
e.g.: the dictionary: `{1:1, 5:5, 6:6, 7:7, 10:10}` 
to the list `[1,0,0,0,5,6,7,0,0,10]`

I'm using this code:

```
for index in xrange(SIZE):
    try:
        list.append(dict[index])
    except KeyError:
        list.append(0)
```

Is there a more pythonic way of doing this? without the use of exceptions?
Thanks,
Niv

Comment: `list.append(dict.get(index, 0))`? But you shouldn't name your own lists and dictionaries `list` and `dict`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the dictionary [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method:

```
for index in xrange(SIZE):    
    L.append(D.get(index, 0))
```

Also, choose other names for the variables instead of `list`and `dict` to avoid naming conflicts with the Python's [built-ins](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html).

Answer (score 2):

### List comprehension

This is nice candidate for a list comprehension:

```
>>> indices = {1:1, 5:5, 6:6, 7:7, 10:10}
>>> SIZE = max(indices.keys()) + 1
>>> [indices.get(index, 0) for index in range(SIZE)]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 10]
```

### Variation

This version with an `if` expression is bit longer:

```
[indices[index] if index in indices else 0 for index in range(SIZE)]
```

### Speed

The version with `get` is bit slower:

```
%timeit [indices.get(index, 0) for index in range(SIZE)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.35 µs per loop

%timeit [indices[index] if index in indices else 0 for index in range(SIZE)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.58 µs per loop
```